# Which datatype for flag?

Tags: mysql, database, flags

Which datatype should I use for a flag (in MySQL)?  I just want to check if a user is online at the moment.
I thought about a [TINYINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html) or [SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html) which both could be 0 or 1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`TINYINT` is perfect for what you are suggesting:

```
`status` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

Comment: Note that an unsigned tinyint(1) can still store values from 0 – 255.

Answer (score 3):

Dear Tinyint is better for flag because it's very small int and it also save your bytes more than other. You can also choose char(1) but i will recommend you choose tinyint

Comment: Why would you recommend tinyint over char(1)?

Comment: @JonathanClark datatypes. Tinyint is an int, char is a string. If you are pulling values from the DB and do boolean (=== vs ==) conditionals a '1' will not behave the same as a 1.

Comment: @MikePurcell Makes sense, although all the ORMs / DB Driver's I've ever used return strings irregardless of the database data type.  From my research, Char(1) and TinyInt(1) are both 1 byte, so overall I agree, may as well use TinyInt...

Comment: @JonathanClark ya one of the BIG downsides of php is loose data typing, on which ORMs are built. With our current ORM we added a getter/setter upstream so anything that is_numeric gets automatically cast to an int (except for floats). Ensures consistent data type from DB to presentation and back.

Answer (score 2):

TINYINT is the same as a boolean type in MySQL, where 0 is false and 1 is true. You can enter in true or false and it will get evaluated to 1 or 0.